# What is the meaning of "all-out dignity must go"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Visit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRRFnPrkFEs
about 7:15 into this video, Trevor said, "all-out dignity must go".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible Trevor said instead: "All our dignity must go", not "All out dignity must go".  When he made this statement he was imitating a hard sales pitch advertisement, and in the context of an advertisement the phrase "all our nnnn must go" means that a store must get rid of all of their nnnn.

A stereo store might say "All our stereos must go" to indicate they will reduce sales prices on them until they have all sold.

An auto dealership might say "all our cars must go" to mean that they will sell cars at any price to make room for the new model year cars.